# Accessing a variable outside the for loop in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am setting a variable as shown below..

```
<xsl:variable name="FoundFloating"> <xsl:value-of select="'no'" />
    </xsl:variable>
```

Now I am doing some processing as shown below ..

```
<xsl:if  test="$abcid=$def_id"> 
<xsl:for-each "$abcd">
                    <xsl:variable name="abcRate"> <xsl:value-of select="./def_Period/"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$abcdf !=$abcRate">
                        <xsl:variable name="$FoundFloating"> <xsl:value-of select="yes" />
                            </xsl:variable>
                        </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Now after this xsl for I am evaluating as shown below.. But my query is that whether `foundfloating` variable is accessible as the for loop is already ended..

```
<xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$FoundFloating='yes'">  <xsl:value-of select="'AAA'" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'BBBA'" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
```

Now after this xsl for I am evaluating as shown below.. But my query is that whether `foundfloating` variable is accessible as the for loop is already ended..
Please advise on this as I have updated the post

Comment: No, the **FoundFloating** variable will not be accessible outside the for loop, as it will only be local in scope. In fact, it will only be accessible inside the **xsl:when** statement it is defined in. But don't panic, there is almost certainly a way to write your XSLT to achieve what you want, but to do so, can you show the condition you are evaluating in the **xsl:for-each** statement, and the full definition of **abcRate**. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC Thanks have updated Please advise how this can be achieved Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that variables are immutable in XSLT. This means once declared, they cannot be changed. What is actually happening in your XSLT sample is you are declaring a whole new variable, with the same name.

The **FoundFloating** variable you are declaring within the for loop will not be accessible outside the for loop, as it will only be local in scope. In fact, it will only be accessible inside the xsl:when statement it is defined in. It is a different variable to the global one you defined, and only exists in the loop.

You don't really need the loop here. You can combine the condition in the **xsl:for-each** and the condition in the **xsl:when** into a single variable declaration.

```
<xsl:if test="$abcid=$def_id"> 
   <xsl:variable name="FoundFloating">
      <xsl:if test="$abcd[def_Period != $abcdf]">yes</xsl:if>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$FoundFloating='yes'">
```

(This replaces the **xsl:for-each** statement entirely)

In fact, this can be simplified even more, by simply setting **FoundFloating** to the node itself (if there is one), rather than "yes"

```
<xsl:if test="$abcid=$def_id"> 
   <xsl:variable name="FoundFloating" select="$abcd[def_Period != $abcdf]" />
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$FoundFloating">
```

This works because the essence of the test is whether a certain node exists matching the condition. Rather than setting a variable to "Yes" or "No" if it exists or not, the variable is set to the node itself. Then, if it does the exist the statement `<xsl:when test="$FoundFloating">` returns true, but false if it doesn't.

So, you don't need the **xsl:for-each** loop, and you only need to declare the **FoundFloating** variable once.

Comment: can you explain the second option in more detail please, Thanks in advance

Comment: I've added more detail for the second option.

Comment: @user 3262517 I've expanded my answer even more to explain how variables are 'immutable' in XSLT.