# accessing a variable outside the for loop as it requires in xsl block

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using the below xsl tag in which initially a variable is declared..

```
<xsl:variable name="FoundFloating"> <xsl:value-of select="'no'" />
            </xsl:variable>
```

WHICH IS USED IN THE BELOW BLOCk

```
        <xsl:for-each select="$abcd/rty">
            <xsl:variable name="rate"> <xsl:value-of select=".ert/Rate" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:if test="$rate!=$wer_first">
                    <xsl:variable name="$FoundFloating">
                        <xsl:value-of select="yes" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each> 



    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$FoundFloating='yes'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'AAA'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'BBB'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

now the issue is that after xsl:dor I am not able to access the value of variable found floating please advise how can I access the value of variable found floating outside for loop

please advise on this

Comment: This looks supsiciously similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522194/accessing-a-variable-outside-the-for-loop-in-xsl. Why did you ask again?

Comment: That isn't how XSLT works.  You need to step back a level or two - tell us what higher-level goal you're trying to achieve and we may be able to suggest a better way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Variables have a certain scope, that is, a range wherein they can be accessed. *Global* variables (top-level declarations) can be accessed anywhere in your stylesheet. *Local* variables cannot be used outside the `xsl:template` or `xsl:for-each` they are declared in.

In other words, if you declare a variable inside `xsl:for-each`, it is impossible to access from outside.

Simply declare this variable outside of the "loop":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:variable name="FoundFloating">
      <xsl:value-of select="'no'" />
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="$abcd/rty">
      <!--......-->
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In your stylesheet, the value of `$FoundFloating` depends on other local variables. Their definitions must be global, too if you want them to be accessible anywhere.

Too many variables can make your XSLT code difficult to read. Please use them sparingly and only when you're really in need of them.